# @RefreshScope with different *.properties files

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I want to reload multiple config files when the refresh endpoint is called. It works perfectly fine with the entries in the application.properties file. Any other file does not refresh.

Here a small example:

pom.xml

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

application.properties

```
greeting=Hi
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh
```

test.properties

```
test=Test
```

ConfigFileHolder1

```
@Repository
@PropertySource(value="application.properties")
@RefreshScope
public class ConfigFileHolder1 {
    @Value("${greeting}")
    private String greeting;
    
    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

ConfigFileHolder2

```
@Repository
@PropertySource(value="test.properties")
@RefreshScope
public class ConfigFileHolder2 {
    
    @Value("${test}")
    private String test;
    
    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

ApiController

```
@Controller
@RefreshScope
public class ApiController implements Api {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigFileHolder1 config1;
    
    @Autowired
    private ConfigFileHolder2 config2;

   // do something with config1 and config2
   ...
}
```

Only ConfigFileHolder1 will refresh its value after the refresh-endpoint is called. To refresh the value of ConfigFileHolder2 the application has to restart.

What do I have to change to refresh the values of all my config-files/ConfigFileHolder?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It appears to refresh because it "loads" the `application.properties` which is a default file, which will be reloaded automatically. The files you want to reload are the default ones loaded by Spring Boot automatically. You should pass your `test.properties` to that list of files.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? I tried to search for something like that before asking my question but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: pass in the names of files to load using `spring.config.location` or `spring.config.additional-location`.

Comment: I added --spring.config.additional-location=classpath:test.properties to my run configuration arguments and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want me to accept your answer please leave a real answer and not only a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@RefreshScope` will only work with the properties loaded by Spring Boot, not the `@PropertySource`s loaded later in the process. Hence you will need to tell Spring Boot to load the additional [configuration files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

You can do this by either adding names  (`spring.config.name`) or locations `spring.config.additional-location`.

When specifying an additional name make sure to include the default `application` as well else that won't be loaded anymore.

```
--spring.config.name=application,test
```

When specifying the above as a parameter all locations will be checked for both an `application.properties` and `test.properties` and also the expansion for profiles will be applied.

```
--spring.config.additional-location=classpath:test.properties
```

This will only load the `test.properties` from the class path and will make it more or less impossible to change the file at runtime but the file will be loaded from that exact location. No profile expansion will be applied.